# Google Charts Image. Data graph line is not according to axis

Tags: graph, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Chart Image to make graphical chart. I am using PHP to provide the data to the link which in return gives me desired chart. The x-axis and y-axis values are also dynamic i.e. if the graph data is 23,45,37,29... then the y-axis value will range from 20 to 50 and if it is more then that then it will scale according to the data..

Now the problem I am not able to solve is that the dynamic values work fine but I am not able to move the graph line. The image below will clear this point:

[Click here for the graph image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSPIF.png)

The data provided to this graph is = 190.12,185.53,186.22,186.71,185.87,185.57,186.50,186.58,190.71,191.41,190.12185

The data range is approx between 180 to 190 but graph drawn is between 198 and 200.

I have used chxr to scale the axis. and the link which I am dynamically updating through php is:

[THIS](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chxt=x,y&chxr=0,20,200%7C1,180,200&chs=600x400&chd=t:190.12,185.53,186.22,186.71,185.87,185.57,186.50,186.58,190.71,191.41,190.12185&chds=a&cht=lc&chco=0066FF&chdl=Sensor%20readings&chdlp=r&chdls=0000CC&chxl=0%3a%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27&chg=12,7,1,0,10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem you've got is that you're scaling the axis labels, but not the axis itself. You want to change the `chds` parameter from `a` to the range you're dealing with.

[This chart](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chxt=x,y&chxr=0,20,200%7C1,180,200&chs=600x400&chd=t:190.12,185.53,186.22,186.71,185.87,185.57,186.50,186.58,190.71,191.41,190.12185&chds=180,200&cht=lc&chco=0066FF&chdl=Sensor%20readings&chdlp=r&chdls=0000CC&chxl=0%3a%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27%7C13-08-27&chg=12,7,1,0,10) looks okay to me.

Comment: I was using wrong encoding previously. To overcome this problem:
1. Use custom scaling. The data in chd variable must look like-

t:<data1>,<data2>....

2. As @Jeremy Faller said, define the range of chds parameter. I was using "a" which is automatic scaling.

3. Most Important, the values/range of chds variable and chxr must be same. 

More details:
https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/data_formats